# Missing begin document in latex file with multiple chapters

Tags: pdftex

Interesting point is that until yesterday I ran this code easily without getting any error but suddenly it keep sending the error of missing begin document. I see some similar question and it was suggested to copy the file as some special format and I don't know how to do that. My file has multiple chapters and I type other part of my works in 5 other latex file. 
Would you please help me with that?
thanks
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt]{report}
% all required packages
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}


\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
           \markboth{#1}{\thechapter\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
            \markright{\thesection\ #1}}


\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \input{A-Introduction/Introduction}
    \chapter{Preliminaries and Notions}
    \input{B-Preliminaries/Preliminaries}
    \chapter{Backbone Colouring}
    \input{C-Studysofar/Studysofar.tex}
    \chapter{Algorithm for Finding Backbone}
    \input{D-Mine/Mine.tex}
    \chapter{Conclusion}
    \input{E-Conclusion/Conclusion.tex}

\doublespacing
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Figures}
\end{document}
```

and here is the error that I got, I copy and paste the part of it:

```
   ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.1 +
% Copyright (c) 2012
You're in trouble here. Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
Missing character: There is no + in font nullfont!
Overfull \hbox (20.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1--5
[]
[]
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\report.cls"
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to a *minimal* example that reproduces the problem. That will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Ok, you can see the error follow this proccess: make a copy of your file, and add the code little by little (running the code) until appears some error.

Comment: Well, if I comment out the `\input` statements, it runs

Comment: @Arny maybe this runs if you write `\chapter` command into each corresponding file

Comment: Actually when I run each of these 5 files separately everything is fine.

Comment: You have posted your (far too long) example **twice** and not posted the error message. after "and here is the error that I got, I copy and paste the part of it:"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I did not notice there were two posts -- I corrected the formatting right now -- however, two posts are too much ;-) And the error message is still missing

Comment: sorry you are right. How can I edit it?

Comment: @Arny: Do you see the `edit` 'button`, bottom left of the post?

Comment: What does this mean: "Actually when I run each of these 5 files separately everything is fine."?  Do the `\input`-ed files work on their own?  If so, you probably can't simply `\input` them....

Comment: @Arny but your example should _only_ include the packages you need to demonstrate the problem, not every package you used in the thesis (several of which are specified twice) similarly delete all the `\input` lines  except for one sample file that demonstrates whatever problem you have.

Comment: For example I can run file mine and studysofar separately with some changes like adding begin document and removing theorems...

Comment: @Arny... Adding **one** `\begin{document}` is a good idea, but at that right place ;-) You seem to have a stray `+` in your code before `\begin{document}`

Comment: The error message clearly shows the problem you have a stray `+` before the copyright comment

Comment: What If I removed this part?  \chapter{Introduction}
    \input{A-Introduction/Introduction}
    \chapter{Preliminaries and Notions}
    \input{B-Preliminaries/Preliminaries}
    \chapter{Backbone Colouring}
    \input{C-Studysofar/Studysofar.tex}
    \chapter{Algorithm for Finding Backbone}
    \input{D-Mine/Mine.tex}
    \chapter{Conclusion}
    \input{E-Conclusion/Conclusion.tex}I think it shouldn't give me any error but still I got the same error?

Comment: As I say, you have a `+` on line one of your file. the error is before the `\documentclass` so editing anything after that will make no difference.

Comment: That's what the error message means: `l.1 +`  == rogue + on line 1.

Comment: But next time _please_ post a more reasonable example document. You posted 178 lines of code that no one else can run (as it inputs files we don't have) and it didn't even include the line generating the error.

Comment: I don't understand. How can I ask my question if it has multiple input? Or if I'm not sure which packages may cause this problem. I edit my question. If you think it's may not be useful for others just delete this question!

Answer (score 9):

You have a `+` on line one of your file which is not in a comment so TeX tries to typeset it before the `\documentclass` (and before `\begin{document}`). Hence the error message.

Comment: An accidental click. Not sure how that happened. I'll remove it when I can.

Comment: @IanThompson If David edits this, you'll be able to reverse the damage :) Perhaps a MWE could be added that shows the obvious problem and produces the same error.

Comment: @IanThompson :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- I blame these GUI driven websites. If only everything worked using emacs shortcuts...

Comment: @IanThompson bring back `w3-mode` ..